# The node element is deleted only the second time by function JS

Tags: javascript

The node element is deleted only the second time, and those created using the add function are deleted the first time

```js
function move(o) {
  var parent = o.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild(o);
  parent.insertBefore(o, parent.firstChild);
}

function add() {
  var node = document.createElement('li');
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("new");
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  node.setAttribute("onclick", "move(this)");
  document.getElementById("table").appendChild(node);
  id = "myList"
}

function del() {
  o = document.getElementById("table");
  o.removeChild(o.firstChild);
}
```

```html
<ol id='table'>
  <li onclick="move(this)">1</li>
  <li onclick="move(this)">2</li>
  <li onclick="move(this)">3</li>
  <li onclick="move(this)">4</li>
  <li onclick="move(this)">5</li>
  <li onclick="move(this)">6</li>
</ol>
<button onclick="add()">Append</button> <button onclick="del()">Del</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
o.removeChild(o.firstElementChild);
```

in your del() function.

So this is the updated code:

```
<ol id="table">
  <li onclick="move(this)">1</li>
  <li onclick="move(this)">2</li>
  <li onclick="move(this)">3</li>
  <li onclick="move(this)">4</li>
  <li onclick="move(this)">5</li>
  <li onclick="move(this)">6</li>
</ol>
<button onclick="add()">Append</button> <button onclick="del()">Del</button>
<script>
  function move(o) {
    var parent = o.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(o);
    parent.insertBefore(o, parent.firstChild);
  }
  function add() {
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("new");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    node.setAttribute("onclick", "move(this)");
    document.getElementById("table").appendChild(node);
    id = "myList";
  }
  function del() {
    o = document.getElementById("table");
    o.removeChild(o.firstElementChild);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The firstChild is not an LI but a textnode

Use

```
 o.removeChild(o.firstElementChild);
```

Also delegate the click

```js
const table = document.getElementById("table")
table.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName==="LI") {
    move(tgt);
  }
})
function move(o) {
  var parent = o.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild(o);
  parent.insertBefore(o, parent.firstElementChild);
}

function add() {
  var node = document.createElement('li');
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("new");
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  table.appendChild(node);
}

function del() { 
  table.removeChild(table.firstElementChild);
}
```

```html
<ol id='table'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ol>
<button onclick="add()">Append</button> <button onclick="del()">Del</button>
```